# .net Core 6 Blazor SignalR connection problem

Tags: .net-core, signalr

So I have written an auction site and I'm using SignalR to live update the components when bids are made, so the user doesn't have to refresh the browser to see new bids.

I also gave the ability to watch multiple auctions at a time - each auction component makes a connection to the hub to get the bid updates when somebody bids... This is all working pretty good

The problem is - if the user refreshes the page anyway, the connections start to multiply and the old dead connections never seem to drop off, so eventually I hit the 5000 connection limit and my page crashes :/

I put my hubconnection stuff in the individual component's OnInitializedAsync event

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        

        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(_navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("auctionhub"), options => { options.Cookies = container; })
            .WithAutomaticReconnect()
            .Build();

        hubConnection.ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        hubConnection.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        hubConnection.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);

        hubConnection.On("UpdateBids", () => GetAuction());
        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }
```

Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

Recently added the server timeout, handshake, and keepalive values